# Check if webpages are reachable with php and refresh it with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

At the moment I’ve got one function to check, if a webpage is reachable. I’ll call this function at about 100 times in a while-loop, which means it sometime lasts 5 minutes to check all these 100 webpages.
I never before used ajax but I would think that it would be a good idea to solve this problem with ajax, but I never used ajax before and have no idea, how to start. Could you give me a good hint? Thanks for every answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use jquery-ajax, makes it simpler.
So put jquery on your site to start.

This is how jquery ajax works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '--LINK TO PHP/ASP...---',  // Place the link that has the command
    data: dataString,  // dataString is a json encode of the data that is sent to the file
    dataType : 'json',
    beforeSend:function(){
        // Before you send the info, do what you want here (ie loading gif...)
    },
    success:function(data){
        // If it is successful, then it will do what you want here.         
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Bare in mind that AJAX only works on the same domain - if it's another site that he wants to check, you'd have to create a script on the server to check the status and return it via AJAX

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [JQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), easier to implement.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From your (somewhat ill-defined) description, I'd say that using AJAX to control the web site verification would be a deeply in-appropriate approach.

Instead, a more sensible approach would be to "batch process" the web site data via the use of a cron triggered PHP cli script.

As such, once you'd inserted the relevant domains into a database table with a "processed" flag set as false, the background script would then:

1. Scan the database for web pages that aren't marked as checked within your required time period.
2. Carry out the CURL lookup, etc.
3. Update the database record accordingly with the current timestamp.

   ...

To ensure no overlap with an existing executing batch processing script, you should only invoke the php script every five minutes from cron and (within the PHP script itself) check how long the script has been running at the start of the "scan" stage and exit if its been running for four minutes or longer. (You might want to adjust these figures, but hopefully you can see where I'm going with this.)

By using this approach, you'll be able to leave the background script running indefinitely (as it's invoked via cron, it'll automatically start after reboots, etc.) and simply add web pages to the database/review the results of processing, etc. via a separate web front end.

You could of course use AJAX to get a regular summary of the current status from the database for the purposes of client-side display.